# MySQL Loop of Inserts

Tags: mysql, database, loops, stored-procedures

I want to copy some rows data to another table, *For example:*

I have this **2** Tables: (`qa_items_purchases`), (`qa_suppliers_invoices`)

`qa_items_purchases`, Data:

[image]

`qa_suppliers_invoices` is Empty:

[image]

I need to copy all records contained in the table (qa_items_purchases), extracting only the fields that the other table has.

**EDIT:**
Between the tables there is variation in the names then:

```
purchase_code AS itempurchase_code
supplier_invoice_code AS item_invoicecodesupplier
supploer_invoice_date as itempurchase_date
```

Comment: so what's wrong? Use `insert select` statement...

Comment: @Sebas - Nothing wrong but OP most likely doesn't know it exists. You should write it as an answer *(with a bit of explanation offcourse)*

Comment: Yeah, I usually do, when not 100% of what I'm going to write is in the mysql manual...

Comment: @Sebas - I know, right?  I mean people should obviously be able to connect their problems to concepts that they are not aware of, and then be able to find that information.  There definitely shouldn't be a site out there to help people answer the questions that they have in a Q and A format...

Comment: What I try to avoid is to write an INSERT STATEMENT for Record, make it quite automatic.

Comment: @StefanH I guess everybody puts an intellectual limit to what they think is worth asking or not, in my case here was my opinion on this matter. Everything is fine though, there's an answer already.

Comment: @Sebas I understand that every the one who has his intellect, but nobody is born knowing the syntax and commands.

Comment: @Sebas - following that reasoning, you can easily delete 90% of all questions here.

Comment: That's ok, this is a participative website and therefore every opinion comes to be constructive. I gave mine, that's it :-)
@JohnNuñez please, don't tell me that. Every day I'm discovering by myself new syntaxes corresponding to new problems I'm facing. There are just 2 types of people outthere, these who always ask and others who always answer...

Comment: @Sebas - let's agree that we don't agree then ;)

Comment: @Sebas, there's nothing wrong with your comment except maybe tone. I often give similar comments like "Other than [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)?" The OP will then answer, oh, I didn't know about that, thanks, or they'll provide further explanation. You also often see "What have you tried?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO qa_suppliers_invoices (purchase_code,supplier_code, user_code, status_code, supplier_invoice_code,supplier_invoice_date)

SELECT itempurchase_code,supplier_code, user_code, status_code,item_invoicecodesupplier,itempurchase_date FROM qa_items_purchases
```

Comment: You should surround braces on table columns. `tablename( purch...`.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT SELECT MANUAL, Visit 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

```
insert into qa_suppliers_invoices 
(purchase_code, supplier_invoice_code, supploer_invoice_date )
SELECT itempurchase_code, item_invoicecodesupplier, itempurchase_date
FROM qa_items_purchases
```

if you need more colums, just add cols.
cols sequence is important.